# How can I connect the CSS file to the HTML file?

Tags: html, css

I use this code for HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TestSite</title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</head>
</html>
```

And this code for CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: may be you have mispelled your css file name or the css file will be in parent directory,  if so then use './site.css'

Comment: Move your h1 outside the head and into your missing body element.

Answer (score 0):

You already have it in your code :

```
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You rename your css file site.css and you put it in the same folder of your html file !